# Why does my jQuery selector select all anchors inside the list element?

Tags: jquery, html, nested, html-lists, css-selectors

Been struggling with this simple selector problem a couple of hours now and must be missing something obvious. I have a `<ul>` in which some `<li>`s have nested `<ul>`s. Each `<li>` contains a link and when this is clicked I want to execute a function (rather than navigate), but importantly, this should only happen for the links contained in the parent `<ul>` and not any links that may be present in a nested `<ul>`. Simple you'd think:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="dontleavethis.page">A link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="navigate.there">A nested link</a></li>
            <li><a href="navigate.somewhere">Another nested link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li:has(ul) a').click(function() { 
    bla bla bla...
    return false;
});
```

Thing is, no matter how I phrase my selector, I cannot stop the links in the nested `<ul>` from triggering the click handler. They clearly do not match the `":has(ul)"` criteria of the selector but the handler still gets attached for some reason. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('li:has(ul) > a').click(...)
```

Your problem is that `$('li:has(ul) a')` means *all* `a` elements inside the `li` that `has` the `ul`, not only immediate children.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul > li:has(ul) > a').click(function(){
    bla bla bla....
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, no dice. I get exactly the same behaviour from this. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Um, this is exactly the same thing as the answer you accepted... only it has the ul in there too (which won't change anything).

Answer (score 0):

If you give the top level links a class you can access them directly, without the need for any complex(ish) selector logic.

Comment: this means that for every link a class is inserted, which clutters the html and generates unnessecary bandwidth. just giving the parent a class/id and selecting only direct ancestors is a lot more efficient

Comment: true but the other selectors being offered are reliant on the DOM structure remaining consistent, which can cause trouble moving forward.  classes can also offer a descriptive selector, making the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the main ul an id, I'll use "main" but you should try and think of a more descriptive one (for your own benefit). Then you can just use

```
$('ul#main > li > a').click(function() { 
    bla bla bla...
    return false;
});
```

The > will select only the direct ancestor of an element.

-edit-
never mind, this also means the li's without an ul in it will have the style. @idrumgood's solution is best.

Comment: Yep, that will work of course. Was hoping there was a neat way to do it without having to assign an ID or class (the parent element of the list already has an ID).

Answer (score 0):

could it be that the event is propagated?

how about

```
$('ul > li:has(ul) > a').click(function(event){
  bla bla bla....
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```